# How do I use a support table to replace certain strings in another table in BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, events, replace, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I have a large table of GA4-based data in BigQuery that I use as a database of specific conversions I track for my website.
One of the columns is called Event_Action. These are all specific conversion events fed in from GA4. The table has a row for each time this action occurs, with the date and some other data, like which campaign triggered it.
Since this data is going to be used for reporting dashboards, we want to change the names of the events from their GA4 names (for example 'click_email') to more user friendly names like (in this case, 'Email Click').

As far as I understand, it's best to use a support table for this rather than chaining a complex series of REPLACE queries. I've set up a support table which has the old names of the event and the new names, and I've named these columns Oldname and NewName. This will let us amend the names affected by the query easily without changing the code.

What I want to do is to create a query that replaces each use of an old name in the Event_Action column with the new name. How do I do this?

I should also mention that I'm a SQL beginner and doing this largely myself, so I'd appreciate a very 'for dummies' type answer as I don't really know what I'm doing in terms of the coding. Let me know if anything is unclear.

I've tried a few different solutions based on examples on StackOverflow, but I get various errors and it simply does not work.

Here's one example:

WITH `bigquery-389215.sheets_upload.conversion_name_table` AS (SELECT "OldName" as OldValue, "NewName" as NewValue)
SELECT 'Event_Action' FROM `bigquery-389215.sheets_upload.conversion_feed_testing`,
SELECT `bigquery-389215.sheets_upload.conversion_feed_testing`.OldValue, `bigquery-389215.sheets_upload.conversion_name_table`.NewValue FROM `bigquery-389215.sheets_upload.conversion_feed_testing`,
JOIN `bigquery-389215.sheets_upload.conversion_name_table` ON `bigquery-389215.sheets_upload.conversion_feed_testing`.OldValue = `bigquery-389215.sheets_upload.conversion_name_table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly you simply need to join to your conversion table like so.

```
SELECT b.NewValue, a.*
FROM bigquery-389215.sheets_upload.conversion_feed_testing a 
INNER JOIN bigquery-389215.sheets_upload.conversion_name_table b on a.Event_Action = b.OldValue
```

Note the query above will exclude records if you don't have a mapping in your conversion table.  If you want to determine if you're missing mappings then use a LEFT JOIN instead of the INNER JOIN and filter on record where NewValue are null.